# mysql phpMyAdmin Privileges

Tags: mysql

I have a new host provider and when I went into phpmyadmin under privileges

I saw

```
User = Any
Host = %
Password = --
Global privileges = USAGE
Grant = No
```

What exactly does this mean?
Anyone can access the database from anywhere without password?!?!

There is also a root@localhost user

thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html):

> The USAGE privilege specifier stands for “no privileges.” It is used
>   at the global level with GRANT to modify account attributes such as
>   resource limits or SSL characteristics without affecting existing
>   account privileges.

It *might* let you make open a connection, but you wouldn't be able to do *anything* with it.